# How to prevent the clone objects disappear after postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i use jquery to create clone dropdownlist everytime add button clicked. For some reason, i have to do the validation checking inside the save event function. Once there is error, a alert message will pop and stop the function. After that, the clone objects will disappear due to the postback. Is there anyway to prevent it disappear or any others way to stop the postback after the alert message.

*Noted: the validation checking must do inside save event function for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `return false` from the javascript function to stop postback

*HTML*

```
<asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" onclickclick="return validation();" />
```

*Javascript*

```
function validation()
{
    //validation code 
    return false;
}
```

If you want to get the object created on client using javascript then you will need to put the information in some hidden field and using that information to create server control on postback. You can use [asp.net ajax UpdatePanel[1](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) for simple and straight forwards solution.

Comment: But i have to know when to stop the postback once the save button clicked. For example, a boolean return true or false to check whether return false or not. If i just return false, the save function will never work. The problem is the validation have to check inside the save function, so i have no idea how to pass the bool to the front-end side.

Comment: You will need to perform validation on client side, why dont you use the validators provided by asp.net

Comment: Because i have to use a list that i get inside the save function to perform the validation

Comment: You can get the control and their data on client as well

Comment: You can also store the information of clone objects in some hidden field and later get to render server control but it is quite complex. You can use asp.net ajax UpdatePanel for simple and straight forwards solution, check my updated answer.